# How can i use Bootstrap file upload Twice in a single page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i use Bootstrap file upload Twice in a single page, am referring the following link. When i use this twice in a page then it shows the same uploaded file. please check this link 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/input-file-popover-preview-image

Comment: Can you please tell what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda I used twice the Html  code in a single page but jquery code used only one time. iam trying to use this in different area in same page

Comment: if there are 2 HTML elements of the same name and you put that name in the selector than jquery will make changes to both of them..check this example <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
 $("p").css("color","red");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: PLEASE check this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/DTcHh/20153/

Comment: they use javascript and jquery. you have edit those.better if you can move to another file upload code.

Comment: @ Sandun Chathuranga i got the result :)